# Minimum Covariance

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance

I have a question that I got stuck on for a while.

Let $Y_1,Y_2,…,Y_n$ be a rendom variable in (Ω,p), for $1\leq i \leq n$ we get that $Y_i$~$Unif\{1,-1\}$.
let $c\in R$ and for any $i\neq j$ let $COV(Y_i,Y_j) = c$.
prove that $c≥-\frac{1}{n-1}$

I know that $COV(x,y)=E[xy]-E[x]E[y]$.
$E[Y_i] = E[Y_j] = 0$.
But I'm not Sure how to approach $E[Y_iY_j]$

Comment: $Y_i$ is a discrete rv and takes on 1 of 3 values {-1,0,1} , right?

Comment: @cineel $Y_i$ is a discrete random Variable and takes 1 of 2 values {-1,1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

With these information, you should be able to get the inequality.

$$Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \right)=\sum_{i=1}^n Var(Y_i)+2\binom{n}{2}c$$
$$E[Y_i^2]=1$$
$$E[Y_i]=0$$

$$Var\left( Y_i\right)=1$$

Comment: $0\leq n+n(n-1)c \implies 0\leq 1+(n-1)c$